# How can I scroll with an overlay on Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, scroll, pseudo-element

In chrome and safari I am over to scroll through the content with an overlay created with an ::after pseudo class.

In firefox I am unable to.

I have tried changing the z-index but then the gradient is hidden.

Changing `top: 80%` but the gradient doesn't have the desired effect and 20% of the height is still no scrollable.

Is there a better solution for this?

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <div>
        <p>
        Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus.
        In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat.
        Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer
        vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla
        mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam
        quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In
        sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci. Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat.
        Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer
        vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla
        mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam
        quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In
        sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat.
        Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer
        vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla
        mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi.it diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliq
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

**SCSS**

```
body {
background: black;
section {
    position: relative;
    div {
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        p {
            color: white;
        }
        &:after {
            content: " ";
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            top: 0;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(
                top,
                rgba(137, 255, 241, 0) 0%,
                rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%
            );
            /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(
                linear,
                left top,
                left bottom,
                color-stop(0%, rgba(137, 255, 241, 0)),
                color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1))
            );
            /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
                top,
                rgba(137, 255, 241, 0) 0%,
                rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%
            );
            /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(
                top,
                rgba(137, 255, 241, 0) 0%,
                rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%
            );
            /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(
                top,
                rgba(137, 255, 241, 0) 0%,
                rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%
            );
            /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(
                to bottom,
                rgba(137, 255, 241, 0) 0%,
                rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%
            );
            /* W3C */
        }
      }
   }
 }
```

Or the example is set up here on codepen:
https://codepen.io/hellojessicagraham/pen/jpepMv

Answer (score 0):

The `:after` element is on top of the `div` preventing the element to be focused => scrolled.

Try to put the `overflow-y: scroll` on the `section` instead